# How do I get username from the id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

I want to get the name of the caller by the caller_id. Name is in the user table.

Here's the migration file.

```
class AddCallerIdToSeller < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :caller_id, :string
  end
end
```

This is the view that I am currently doing.

```
 <td class="text-center"><%= call_report.caller_id.present? %></td>
```

When i do like above, it shows true. But I want to get the user name which is "=" caller_id

Comment: Instead of just checking if it's present, display it.  Change `call_report.caller_id.present?` to `call_report.caller_id`

Comment: if i change to `call_report.caller_id` , it shows up the caller id only. I want the name of the caller. What i understand is, to get the name of that caller_id, I need to passthrough the users table to get it. but i don't know how :(

Comment: Add an association `belongs_to :caller` to model for `call_report` and in view, do `<%= call_report.caller.name %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
User.find(call_report.caller_id).name
```

The best way to do this in the controller and assign it to some variable there.

Answer (score 1):

If you do this...

```
class CallReport < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You can then do

```
call_report.user.name
```

Also the ID is normally stored as an integer, so it's more typical to see...

```
add_column :users, :caller_id, :integer
```

I'd do a `rake db:rollback` then make the above change then `rake db:migrate`